# How to consume kafka queue every 30 minute in python

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-python

I'm having an issue regarding kafka consumer in python, here is my use case kafka producer will send data every second in real-time streaming. But kafka consumer needs to consume at every 30 minutes and collect batch of data. Help me to resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to process your data real-time, you may want to reconsider, if Kafka is the right solution for you. However, you can try this:

```
 Properties props = new Properties();
 props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
 props.put("group.id", "your_consumer_group");
 props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
 props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
 props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
 props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
 props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
 KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
 consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar"));
 while (true) {
     ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(1000);
     for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
         System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
     }

     // After data is consumed, you make your thread sleep until next 30 min:
     Thread.sleep(30 * 60 * 1000);
 }
```

If you'd like your real-time-batch-processing to be conducted at every 30th or 0th minute of every hour, you can use this sleep instead:

```
Thread.sleep(System.currentTimeMillis() % (30*60*1000));
```

It will make your consumer wake up at `00:00`, `00:30`, `01:00`, `01:30`, etc.
Follow this link for details: https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html

Again, you probably don't want to use kafka this way. It might be better do dump data to some storage (parquet files partitioned by date-time, for example) and do some batch processing on it every 30 minutes.

Comment: Using `Thread.sleep(30 * 60 * 1000);` to introduce delay is not ideal. There has be a kafka way.